# Is Korin the only one able to grow Senzu Beans?

Tags: dragon-ball-z

At certain points during the Dragon Ball Z-serie, the group receives a bag of Senzu Beans from Korin. Senzu Beans are very nutritious and heal wounds, sometimes even saving people from life-threatening injuries.

Knowing that, it would be stupid not to have extra Senzu Beans on hand. Unfortunately, the only one who's able to grow them is Korin.

*Is there a reason why nobody else can grow Senzu Beans, other than difficulty?* I'd imagine regular people can learn to grow beans, even if they're magical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An [entry for Korin](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Korin) in the Dragon Ball [wikia](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page) states that, ***Korin is the only one who grows the Senzu Beans which...*** and that 
***Korin Tower is the only place in the world they are grown...***

Apart from that, the [entry for Senzu Beans](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Senzu_Bean) depicts Korin as the inventor of the Senzu Beans.

Based on that, it can be presumed that one of these are true:

1. Korin invented the Senzu Beans and thus he is the only one who can cultivate them.
2. The Senzu Beans need a very particular habitat to grow and Korin Tower happens to be the only place matches its needs.

Do note however, that the wikia does not mention if there was any *explicit* reference to this matter in the Manga.

Comment: Thanks, great answer. Too bad they don't mention any references.

Comment: Indeed. I tried to read the Manga chapters around the part where Goku met Korin for the first time but there really weren't any mention as to why the Senzu Beans can only be found there. Perhaps I missed it or there were mentions later in the storyline. Hopefully, someone who have read the series recently will be able to shed some light.